# Weniger informeller Ausdruck für "weg-abstrahieren"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase, verb, informal

Der Satz

> A und B sind gute Ansätze, welche aber die Eigenschaft E von der Problemstellung P *wegabstrahieren*.

kommt mir sehr umgangssprachlich vor. Ich würde aber gerne diese Bedeutung mit einer formelleren Konstruktion zum Ausdruck bringen.

---

How to replace the expression "*etwas wegabstrahieren*" with a less informal one?

Comment: Das ist wie "vorprogrammieren". "weg" ist nur doppelt gemoppelt.

Comment: Ich glaube vielmehr, dass aber auch abstrahieren hier das falsche Verb ist. Wenn ich die eigentliche Aussage richtig verstehe, muss da so was wie "hinfällig werden, "zunichte machen" hin.

Comment: Ideen: "...welche aber die Eigenschaft C nicht beachten/berücksichtigen" / "...welche aber die Vorteile der Eigenschaft C nicht nutzen / aufheben"

Comment: annullieren, kompensieren...

Comment: @Em1: Danke für den Edit, das machts wirklich klarer. Davon abgesehen kommt "nicht berücksichtigen" dem ganzen nahe, aber ist keine gute Alternative, da es die Bedeutung doch etwas ändert, findest Du nicht?

Comment: Die Frage ist, was genau "(weg)abstrahieren" wirklich bedeuten soll. Abstrahieren im [DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abstrahieren) oder [wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstrahieren). (1) ist es nicht, es wird nicht verallgemeinert, (2) trifft es nur halb. Wobei "vernachlässigen" glaube ich hier ziemlich gut die Sache trifft. "Wegabstrahieren" gibt es imho nicht, und ist wie "vorprogrammieren" nur daraus entstanden, dass man versucht dem Wort eine Bedeutung unterzujubeln, die das Wort eignetlich schon hat.

Comment: Wie auch immer, "abstrahieren" in dem Kontext denke ich ist nicht korrekt. Abstrahieren meint, so verstehe ich das, etwas anbieten, was etw. anderes überflüssig macht, z.b. ein grobes Konzept/Überblick, damit man sich nicht mit den Einzelheiten auseinandersetezen muss. In deinem Kontext - so wie ich ihn verstehe - ist das Problem, dass die Ansätze A und B Eigenschaft E ignorieren.

Comment: Genau genommen... Wenn du sagst, "nicht berücksichtigen" ist schon ganz gut, verändert aber etwas die Bedeutung, bin ich mir doch nicht sicher, ob ich die Bedeutung ganz verstanden habe. Imho können hier zwei Bedeutungen entstehen: "ignorieren/nicht berücksichtigen/..." oder "aufheben/annullieren/(zerstören, hinfällig machen, zu nichte machen)". Also entw. geht E verloren durch A und B, oder E besitzt etw. was A und B nicht ausnutzen... Du scheinst aber noch etwas drittes anzupeilen?!

Comment: Und das "verloren gehen" willst du anscheinend nicht beschreiben, sonst hätte dir splattnes Antwort gefallen.

Comment: @Em1: Danke schonmal für Deine Mühe; Es geht hier um *Simulation*. "überflüssig machen" ist daher der falsche Ausdruck. Das Problem P wird sozusagen als simpleres Problem P' aufgefasst (im softwaretechnischen Sinne ist P eine Verfeinerung von P'), welches die (interessante) Eigenschaft E nicht besitzt. Der Ausdruck "nicht berücksichtigen" scheint zwar zu passen, ist mir aber nicht stark genug, vergleichen mit der Bedeutung des Phantasiewortes "wegabstrahieren" welche in meinem Kopf rumgeistert. Ergibt das einen Sinn?

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass du eine Verdreher hast (wenn P simpler ist, kann es nicht gleichzeitig eine Verfeinerung sein, imho), denke ich, ist es (fast) klarer. Aufgrund des Verdrehers bin ich mir noch nicht sicher, ob das eine Ab- oder Aufleitung ist. Greifen wir hier (um mal aus Sicht eines Softwareentwicklers zu sprechen) auf das Interface zu, dass eine Eigenschaft entw. noch gar besitzt oder eben noch nicht näher beschrieben hat oder auf eine konkrete Instanz, die eben diese Eigenschaft besitzt.

Comment: Sprich, einen Schritt weiter: Falls es also die konkrete Instanz ist, bedeutet es, dass A und B diese Eigenschaft also gar nicht kennen, weil sie denken, sie würden mit dem Interface kommunizieren. Oder greifen A und B tatsächlich auf das Interface zu, aber dort fehlt eben die Eigenschaft?

Comment: Oder: Es gibt also eine Problemstellung P', die diese Eigenschaft E' verwendet. Jetzt abstrahierst (vereinfachst) du das Problem zu P in dem du E wegfallen lässt. -> Dann ist mir aber nicht klar, inwiefern jetzt A und B betroffen sind, da es entw. auch die komplexen Ansätze sind, die auf P zugreifen, oder eben auch abstrahiert werden müssen, so dass sie auf P' zugreifen können..... Verwirrend :( PS: Wer weiß, wie man einen Chat eröffnen kann, wenn das nicht automatisch angeboten wird

Comment: @Em1: Jetzt glaube ich, ich habe Dich mit der "Verfeinerung" auf die falsche Fährte gejagt. Es geht weniger um Interfaces als um Softwareversionen. Mit einer Verfeinerung meine ich das Hinzufügen von Komplexität/Features. Ein Modell wird verfeinert um ein detailierteres Modell zu ergeben, usw. bis irgendwann lauffähige Software dabei rauskommt (ja, in der Praxis ist das nicht so schön, ich weiß). Um auf die Phrase zurückzukommen: A und B können nur auf abstrakterer Ebene Aussagen über das Modell treffen. *Die Erweiterungen des feineren Modells werden also wegabstrahiert.*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4144/discussion-between-bitmask-and-em1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In einem Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4144) mit dem OP konnten wir das Problem genauer eingrenzen und haben mögliche Lösungen gefunden. Im Folgenden werde ich die Kernpunkte zusammenfassen, sprich, ich abstrahiere von den zahlreichen Ideen des Brainstormings. ;)

Die im Kontext wesentliche Definition von [abstrahieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abstrahieren) lautet:

> von etwas, von sich absehen, auf etwas verzichten

Da der OP Wert darauf legt, welche Information konkret bei der Abstraktion verloren geht, und den Bezug zu dieser Information zieht, ergänzt er das Verb *abstrahieren* mit der Vorsilbe *weg*. Dies ist insofern falsch, da diese Vorsilbe dem Wort eine Bedeutung unterzujubeln versucht, welche jedoch schon vorhanden ist. *Abstrahieren* bedeutet auf etw. verzichten bzw. etw. entfernen. Somit ist die Vorsilbe überflüssig und falsch.

Den Satz kann man durchaus korrekt mit dem Verb *abstrahieren* gestalten, zum Beispiel:

> A und B sind gute Ansätze, welche jedoch von der Eigenschaft E der Problemstellung P abstrahieren.

Alternativ zu *abstrahieren* kann man auch sagen *von der Eigenschaft absehen* oder *auf die Eigenschaft verzichten*.

Wie auch immer, letztlich konnten wir dennoch eine zufriedenstellende Lösung finden. Anstatt *abstrahieren* können in dem Kontext eine Vielzahl an Wörtern gefunden werden, die das Auslassen der Information hervorheben, zum Beispiel:

> A und B sind gute Ansätze, welche aber die Eigenschaft E von der Problemstellung P nicht berücksichtigen.
>
> A und B sind gute Ansätze, welche aber die Eigenschaft E von der Problemstellung P vernachlässigen.

Answer (score 4):

Keinesfalls ist **wegabstrahieren** unglücklich gewählt oder gar umgangssprachlich, allenfalls vielleicht ein wenig schwer verständlich.

Wir kennen zwei Bedeutungen von [*"abstrahieren"*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=abstrahieren&view=1):

> - das Wesentliche vom Zufälligen ab-, herleiten, verallgemeinern, zum Begriff erheben.
> - *"absehen, verzichten, außer acht lassen"* und *"absondern, loslösen"*

Unter **Abstraktion** im Sinne der hier relevanten erstgenannten Bedeutung versteht man die durch Nachdenken gewonnene Erkenntnis eines allgemeinen oder übergeordneten Ganzen. Ein schönes Beispiel aus dem psychologischen Abstraktionsbegriff findet man bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraktion):

> Zahlreiche Studien zeigten, dass Menschen im allgemeinen mit drei Abstraktionsstufen pro Begriff auskommen: der mittleren Grundstufe (z. B. „Stuhl“), plus einem abstrakteren Oberbegriff (z. B. „Möbel“) und der konkreteren Stufe der Einzelbeispiele (z. B. „mein Küchenstuhl“).
>   *<sup>M. Eysenck, M. Keane: Cognitive Psychology. Psychology Press, Hove (UK), 2000</sup>*

Durch die Abstraktion zu *"Möbel"* ist also zunächst der Verwendungszweck *"Küche"* und dann das Merkmal *"Stuhl"* verloren gegangen.

Oder, im selben Wikipedia-Artikel zeigt ein Beispiel aus der abstrakten Kunst, wie ein Hirschkäfer in Stufen der Abstraktion dargestellt werden kann, die in der dort höchsten Stufe mit folgendem Bild endet:

[image]

Man kann das Wesentliche noch erkennen, im Abstraktionsprozess sind aber sowohl die Farbe als auch Details der Form verloren gegangen.

Genau diesen Verlust von Detailmerkmalen während der Abstraktion kann man mit dem Begriff **wegabstrahieren** trefflich ausdrücken. Wie in den beiden Beispielen ist auch im Kontext der Frage die Eigenschaft *"E"* wegabstrahiert. Ich wüßte keinen genaueren Begriff, außer vielleicht einer etwas einfacher zu verstehenden  wortreichen Umschreibung:

> Durch die Abstraktion des Problems P ist bei den Ansätzen A und B die Eigenschaft E *verloren gegangen* / *weggelassen worden*.

---

#### Anmerkung zum Präfix [*"weg-"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/weg_)

Kommentare (*"Sorry, aber wegabstrahieren ist absoluter Blödsinn"*) machen deutlich, dass offenbar nicht jeder mit der Funktion des Präfix *"weg-"* vetraut ist. Die Präfigierung eines Verbs mit *"weg-"* hat unter anderem folgende Bedeutung:

> - bezeichnet eine Bewegung von dieser Stelle nach einer anderen.
> - drückt aus, daß etw. mit etw. geschieht, so daß es beseitigt, entfernt wird, nicht mehr vorhanden ist
>     <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=weg-)</sup>

Genau letztere Bedeutung findet man bei *"wegabstrahieren"*, so wie auch bei den Verben *weglassen, wegdiskutieren, wegretuschieren, wegrationalisieren*. Ein Beispiel für die erste Bedeutung wäre *wegtransportieren*.

Natürlich werden **nur die häufigsten prä- oder suffigierten Varianten** in den einschlägigen Lexika gelistet. Das schließt aber die Validität eines Präfix oder Suffix nicht aus.

Comment: Sorry, aber *wegabstrahieren* ist absoluter Blödsinn. Ich habe noch mal gesucht und nicht eine seriöse Quelle gefunden, die das Wort definiert oder auch nur annährend sinnvoll benennt. Der Rest der Erklärung ist recht "abstrakt" formuliert; und durchaus richtig, aber wäre eher ne Antwort zu meiner Frage :D

Comment: Nur dass *abstrahieren* bereits bedeutet, dass etw. ausgelassen wird, somit ist *wegabstrahieren* genau so ein Unwort, wie *vorprogrammieren* (welches sensationeller Weise seinen Weg in den Duden gefunden hat, obwohl in *programmieren* die Bedeutung "vorher" schon drin ist; denn ich kann nicht etwas "nachprogrammieren"). Die Beispiele *weglassen*, *wegdiskutieren*, *wegretuschieren* sind korrekt, bei *wegrationalisieren* bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob dadurch eine neue Bedeutung entstehen kann oder ob die Vorsilbe gar nicht dazu passt. *Wegtransportieren* ist auch OK, wenngleich auch merkwürdig.

Comment: Ach, doch. Ich kann "nachprogrammieren", dass nennt man dann "kopieren", "abschreiben", "klauen" oder wie auch immer. Aber natürlich ist im obigen Kontext mit "nachprogrammieren" was anderes gemeint! (Und diese "andere Bedeutung" macht's immer noch nicht valide, aber das ist ne andere Sache)

Comment: +1 @Takkat: Du hast absolut recht.

Comment: Selbst wenn es rein technisch zulässig ist, scheint es doch nur für sprach-geeks nachvollziehbar zu sein, was es in den Augen des otto-normal-deutsch-Benutzers als Umgangssprache erscheinen lässt. Daher +1 aber kein accept.

Comment: „welches sensationeller Weise seinen Weg in den Duden gefunden hat“ Ich mag mich täuschen, aber schaut der Duden (oder vielmehr dessen Redaktion) nicht dem Volk auf den Mund? War es nicht also quasi vorprogrammiert, dass „vorprogrammieren“ in den Duden gelangt, wenn es nur häufig genug verwendet wird?

Comment: @Clemens Naja, mal davon abgesehen, dass im Dudeneintrag das Wort nirgends als "umgangssprachlich" gekennzeichnet ist, sind außerdem die Beispiele alles andere als umgangssprachlich. Wer sagt bitte "große Fensterfronten programmieren höhere Heizkosten bereits vor". Und wer programmiert den Videorekorder vor? Habe ich auch noch nie gehört...

Comment: @Em1 ich finde die Beispiele auch nicht gerade gelungen... ich meinte überhaupt nicht, dass das Wort umgangsprachlich sein soll. „Handy“ ist auch nicht umgangsprachlich und war trotzdem vor wenigen Jahrzehnten (offensichtlich) noch nicht im Duden. Die Dudenredaktion kann ja nichts dafür, wie ein Wort verwendet wird. Sie kanns höchstens dokumentieren. [Verwendet wird es jedenfalls](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/koalitionskrise-der-naechste-krach-ist-schon-vorprogrammiert-1.1322733).

Comment: Übrigens [selbst von Linguistik-Professoren](http://www.scilogs.de/wblogs/blog/sprachlog/allgemein/2012-07-09/sprachbrocken-2012-24-28) :)

Comment: @Clemens Dass es verwendet wird, ist mir bewusst. Ich habe mir das Wort ja nicht ausgedacht. Und aufgrund zunehmender Verwendung wird das Wort auch irgendwann gang und gäbe sein, aber bis dahin werde ich gegen "vorprogrammieren" ankämpfen, genau so wie auch z.B. gegen die falsche Verwendung von "programmatisch", ein verwandtes Problem ;)

Comment: @Em1 Dein gutes Recht :) Obwohl mir das ein Kampf gegen Windmühlen scheint... Ich habe z.B. aufgegeben, gegen „Sinn machen“ anzureden, obwohl es mich immer noch schüttelt, wenn ich es höre.

Answer (score 1):

"Wegabstrahieren" hört sich überhaupt nicht nach Umgangssprache an. Je nach dem genauen Kontext, der in der Frage nicht angegeben wird, könnte

> ... die Eigenschaft E von der Problemstellung P vernachlässigt ...

eine Lösung sein.