# Kann "abstrahieren" synonym zu "vereinfachen" verwendet werden?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Aus der Frage "[Weniger informeller Ausdruck für weg-abstrahieren?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4910/1224)" und dem [anschließenden Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4144) mit bitmask heraus, bin ich mir nicht mehr sicher, ob ich das Wort abstrahieren richtig verwende.

Das Wort [*abstrahieren*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abstrahieren) bedeutet laut Duden

> 1. aus dem Besonderen das Allgemeine entnehmen, verallgemeinern
> 2. von etwas, von sich absehen, auf etwas verzichten

Zwei Anwendungsbeispiele:

> 1. Wir haben gelernt zu akzeptieren, dass wir statt einer Antwort viele verschiedene Antworten finden, und aus diesen abstrahieren wir die wahrscheinlichste Version und ignorieren die unglaubwürdigen. <sup>[Zeit Online](http://www.zeit.de/digital/internet/2012-02/wir-die-netz-kinder)</sup> <sub>(abstrahieren = ableiten, schlussfolgern)</sub>
> 2. Sie abstrahiert von der schieren Funktion der Aufbewahrung von Büchern und erzählt die Geschichte der Bibliotheken als Geschichte der materialisierten Ordnung von Erkenntnis. <sup>[Zeit Online](http://www.zeit.de/2011/31/Architektur-Bibliothek)</sup> <sub>(abstrahieren = absehen, verzichten)</sub>

Wann immer ich das Wort *abstrahieren* bisher verwendet habe, habe ich das in der Form *jemand/etwas abstrahiert etwas*. Im ersten Beispiel hätte ich zum Beispiel geschrieben:

> Wir haben die Antworten abstrahiert und eine Fassung erstellt, die das Wesentliche zusammenfasst. <sub>(abstrahieren = vereinfachen, durch Auslassung)</sub>

Meine neueste Erkenntnis ist aber, dass das nicht möglich ist und *abstrahieren* nicht in der Form, wie ich es im letzten Satz aufzeige, verwendet werden kann.

Kann *abstrahieren* mit "etwas durch Auslassung vereinfachen" gleichgesetzt werden, oder habe ich das Wort seit jeher falsch verwendet?

Comment: Ich sehe da klare Unterschiede. Ein Mathebeispiel "Erweitere den ersten Term um 2x, erweiter den zweiten um 2a, kürze beide Terme mit 2". Wenn man das vereinfacht, erweitert man gleich um x bzw. a und spart sich das Kürzen. Wird das abstrahiert, heißt es aber: "Bilde den kleinsten gemeinsamen Nenner". Abstrahieren ändert den Blickwinkel (zoomt raus und fasst llogische Einheiten zusammen), vereinfachen ändert Abläufe/Zusammenhänge/Fakten auf einem Abstraktionslevel (spart Umwege, unnötige Terme etc.) und/oder kann in seinem weiterene Sinne als Oberbegriff verwendet werden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich muss zugeben, dass es mir zunehmend schwerer fällt, der Diskussion bzw. der Gedankenentwicklung zu folgen – wird mir langsam zu hoch.

Das Problem ist m. E. einfach, dass es hier um so schwer unterscheidbare Nuancen geht:

Das Wort "abstrahieren" beschreibt streng genommen einen Vorgang aus der Perspektive des Ergebnisses, nicht des Ausgangspunktes. Der folgende Satz ist also richtig:

> <strike>Der Stadtplan ist stark abstrahiert.</strike><sup>siehe Takkats Kommentar</sup>
>   Der Straßenverlauf ist im Stadtplan stark abstrahiert.

Blöderweise ist dieser Satz synonym mit:

> <strike>Der Stadtplan ist stark vereinfacht.</strike>
>   Der Straßenverlauf ist im Stadtplan stark vereinfacht.

Ich finde, es ist daher absolut nachvollziehbar, die beiden Verben als Synonyme zu betrachten, auch wenn es streng genommen nicht korrekt ist.

Zudem ist das vom Duden vorgeschlagene Synonym "verallgemeinern" allenfalls eine Haaresbreite von "vereinfachen" entfernt.

Drittens: Die Vereinfachung macht den größten Teil der Abstraktion aus.

Mein Fazit:

Es ist schon OK, "abstrahieren" so zu verwenden, wie Du es immer getan hast – als Synonym von "vereinfachen". In so gut wie allen Zusammenhängen wird jeder wissen, was Du meinst, und ich wette, dass den wenigsten auffallen würde, dass sich das nicht hundertprozentig mit der Dudendefinition deckt.

Comment: ...zumal die Dudendefinition nur eine Abstraktion der wahren Bedeutung sein kann ;)

Comment: ...und der erste Satz *Der Stadtplan ist stark abstrahiert* nur dann richtig wäre, wenn man **annimmt**, dass die Bedeutung von abstrahiert *vereinfacht* sei.

Comment: Klingt schlüssig :) Aus der Sichtweise habe ich das noch gar nicht betrachtet. Das macht einiges klarer :)

Comment: @Takkat: a) richtig :)
b) möglicherweise richtig - bin mir nicht ganz sicher :)
Werde aber eine zweite Version hinzufügen...

Comment: Ich glaube nicht dass die sätze das gleiche bedeuten. wenn du den strassenverlauf abstrahierst dann werden m.E.n aus dick hezeichneten strassen dünne linien oder mathematische formeln. wenn du ihn vereinfachst, dann lässt du m.E.n einige verbindungen weg.

Answer (score 10):

*Abstrahieren* impliziert eine Betrachtung mit einer anderen Granularität beziehungsweise auf einer anderen (Abstraktions-)Ebene.

Der Satz

> Ein Stadtplan abstrahiert von der Topologie einer Stadt.

bedeutet, dass die Stadt auf den Stadtplan abgebildet wird, aber nicht unbedingt 1 zu 1 mit diesem übereinstimmen muss. Eine Straße ist in der Realität keine Linie.

Im Gegensatz dazu bezeichnet *vereinfachen* nur den Vorgang der Vereinfachung, es ist nicht mit diesem implizierten Perspektivwechsel behaftet. Zum Beispiel:

> Die Formel lässt sich zu A + B = C vereinfachen.

enthält diesen Perspektivwechsel nicht. Die Formel mag lesbarer bzw. einfacher sein, sie bezeichnet allerdings immer noch dieselbe Relation.

Was die Unterscheidung der beiden Begriffe verkompliziert, ist die Tatsache, dass eine Abstraktion oft eine Vereinfachung bewirkt.

Comment: Guter Hinweis, und das mit dem Stadtplan ist ein gutes Beispiel. Dennoch glaube ich, ist dir der selbe Fehler unterlaufen wie mir. In dem Beispiel kann ich "abstrahieren" sehr wohl mit "vereinfachen" ersetzen, im Sinne von: "Ein Stadtplan vereinfacht die Beschreibung der räumlichen Beziehung von Objekten, Straßen, etc. einer Stadt". *Abstrahieren*, so meine neueste Erkenntnis, kann man eigentlich nur "von" oder "aus" etw. Z.b. "Ein Stadtplan abstrahiert von der Komplexität der räumlichen Anordnung" (wobei das auch nicht sauber ausgedrückt ist, aber ich denke du verstehst, was ich sagen will)

Comment: Da hast du recht, "von (etwas) abstrahieren" ist grammatikalisch korrekt. Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch wird das 'von' meist weggelassen. Allerdings habe ich noch nie von der Kombination aus 'aus' und 'abstrahieren' gehört. Könntest du dazu bitte ein konkretes Beispiel geben?

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne das Wort auch nur in den beiden Duden-Bedeutungen. Eine Verwendung, wie von Em1 in der ersten Version seiner Frage gegeben, hätte mich auf jeden Fall aufhorchen lassen.

> "Wir abstrahieren das Regelwerk"

bedeutet für mich, dass wir das Regelwerk aus etwas anderem, meinetwegen einem komplexen Haufen sprachlicher Äußerungen, ableiten. Das, was abstrahiert wird, ist das, was ich am Ende habe.
Dennoch gibt es tatsächlich eine Überlappung der Bedeutung mit *vereinfachen*, wie das zweite (inzwischen auch gelöschte) Beispiel von Em1 sehr schön zeigt. Es klingt zwar etwas komisch in meinen Ohren, jedoch verstehe ich den Sinn.

> Das Testprojekt abstrahiert die Fehlerursache.

heißt, dass das Testprojekt die Ursache aus einem komplexen Ganzen virtuell herausfiltert und in eine abstrakte Form überführt. Und das mit dem Ziel, den Fehler zu verstehen. Hier wird also in der Tat etwas vereinfacht, nämlich ein komplexes System. Unwichtiges wird ausgeblendet etc.
Die Fehlerursache an sich jedoch ist ein festes "Ding". Meinetwegen ein falscher Zeiger. Den kann man nicht vereinfachen, man kann ihn nur suchen, finden und beheben. Aber nicht vereinfachen.
Also alles in allem: Ich denke, der Duden hat keine Bedeutung übersehen und *abstrahieren* ist **nicht** synonym zu *vereinfachen*. Es kann aber dem gleichen Zweck dienen, und geht entsprechend bisweilen in einigen Äußerungen an Stelle von *vereinfachen* als korrekt durch :)

Schlusswort: Durch *abstrahieren* kann man *vereinfachen*.

Answer (score 1):

Wie man in der Mathematik oder der Informatik schon ohne Duden weiß, bedeutet `abstrahieren` nicht zwangsläufig `vereinfachen`, sondern `verallgemeinern`. Und da eine Verallgemeinerung in den meisten Fällen keine Vereinfachung darstellt, würde ich sagen, dass man das auf keinen Fall synonym verwenden kann.

Answer (score 1):

*»Wir haben die Antworten abstrahiert und eine Fassung erstellt, die das Wesentliche zusammenfasst.«*

Ich sehe hier lediglich einen Formulierungsfehler, der darin besteht, das Verb 'abstrahieren' transitiv auf 'die Antworten' zu verwenden. Das Verb stammt vom lateinischen Wort *abstrahere (abstrāctum)* ab:  wegziehen, fortschleppen, gewaltsam trennen, abziehen, abhalten ([s. DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=abstrahieren&submit_button=Suche&view=1)). Es wurden also nicht die Antworten abstrahiert, sondern etwas wurde **von/aus den Antworten** abstrahiert:

> z.B. »Wir haben **von den Antworten** abstrahiert und eine Fassung
>   erstellt, die das Wesentliche zusammenfasst.«

Das gilt für beide Bedeutungen, die im Duden beschrieben werden. (Und trifft auch im Englischen zu.)

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin noch nicht sicher, ob ich die Frage verstanden habe.

Die Frage nach dem Synonym bedeutet für mich, dass ich immer wenn ich A sage auch B sagen könnte, aber auch umgekehrt immer wenn ich B sage auch A sagen kann. Synonyme sind Begriffe die das gleiche bedeuten.

Im Gegensatz dazu stünde der Fall, wenn ich das eine immer für das andere, das andere jedoch nicht immer für das eine sagen könnte. (Mehr noch, wenn ich das eine nur oft für das andere sagen könnte, nur gelegentlich, selten oder nie, natürlich.)

Eine Abstaktion sieht immer von Details ab, und vereinfacht sie wie eine Landkarte die Struktur einer Gegend vereinfacht abbildet. Zum Beispiel sind Symbole für Laub- und Nadelbäume noch in die grünen Waldflächen gesetzt, aber weder kann man sehen wie viele Bäume, noch welche genau dort stehen, oder wie groß sie sind, wie alt, und so weiter.

Man könnte nun anführen, dass Abstraktionen nicht immer einfach sind. Man kann etwa die Kommutativität von Multiplikation (a*b = b*a) und die Kommutativität von Addition (a+b = b+a) eben durch den abstrakten Begriff "kommutativ" bezeichnen, aber dass das eine Vereinfachung ist wird manchen zögern lassen, ist doch abstraktes Denken nicht immer einfach, und dann lateinische Terminologie!

Aber *einfach* ist nicht immer *leicht*. Statt zwei Fällen habe ich nur noch einen, und insofern vielleicht ist es doch einfach: Wenn ich statt "Rehe, Hirsche, Wildschweine und Hasen" zu sagen von "Wild" rede, dem abstrakteren Begriff, dann habe ich nur noch einen Fall, nicht viere.

Ich kann es mir aber auch anders einfach machen, in dem ich nicht abstrahiere, sondern unterschlage. Ich habe vielleicht 20 Ladendiebstähler, die in 18 Fällen von Bedürftigen verübt werden, und sage, Ladendiebstahl sei eine Folge von Armut.

Hier habe ich aber nicht die Gemeinsamkeit der 20 Fälle verallgemeinert, sondern nur von 18, und 2 unter den Tisch fallen lassen. Das ist eine Vereinfachung, die keine Abstraktion mehr ist; daher: Nein, es sind keine Synonyme.

Oder jmd. sagt "Vögel sind die Tiere, die fliegen können", und erfasst weder fliegende Fische, noch Pinguine. Auch hier, eine Vereinfachung, die aber keine Abstraktion ist.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage überarbeitet. Hoffentlich ist sie endlich verständlich. - Deinen ersten Satz möchte ich in Frage stellen. Zwei Wörter müssen nicht zwingend *immer* austauschbar sein. Zum einen können Wörter mehr als eine Bedeutung habe und nur in bestimmten Kontext durch ein bestimmtes anderes ersetzt werden. Außerdem halten viele Wörter eben noch eine Nebenbedeutung, die ein anderes nicht hat. Dadurch kann man manchmal nur in eine Richtung ersetzen, aber nicht in die andere. Was denkst du?

Comment: Gut - räumen wir erstmal die Nebenfrage aus dem Weg. Meine Überprüfungen haben ergeben, dass man 'Synonym' nicht streng als 'gleichbedeutend' auffassen muss. Was dann die Frage ist, ist mir nach noch 2-3 mal lesen noch immer nicht ganz deutlich. Bin ich auf der richtigen Spur, mit dem Absehen von Fällen auf der einen Seite? Wenn wir rote Dreiecke, Kreise und Quader haben, dann abstrahieren wir von der Form, und abstrahieren als Farbe das Rot. Die Frage ist jetzt, ob man auch von 'abstrahieren' reden kann, wenn man vornehmlich rote Objekte aber vereinzelt blaue hat, von denen man absieht?

Comment: Ich bin nie so ins Detail gegangen, mit roten oder blauen Dreiecken oder Kreisen. Es gibt eine Menge X und aus dieser Menge wird nach irgendeinem Schema f ein Untermenge oder sogar etwas neues kreiert. Diese Untermenge, bzw. das Neue, repräsentiert die nach Schema f relevanten Daten oder Fakten. Ob dabei etwas weggelassen, geändert oder sonst was wird, sehe ich nicht als relevant.

Comment: @Em1: Schema-f ist ja eine Filteroperation, die die Teilmenge aus X kreiert. Wenn dieses f nichts ändert/weglässt dann ist f nicht relevant. Wenn f nicht eine Teilmenge bildet, sondern eine Transformation darstellt, dann ist es m.E. keine Abstraktion. Wenn ich die roten Dreiecke kaputtschneide oder anders einfärbe ist das doch keine Abstraktion! Tut mir leid, aber diese Antwort läßt mich noch ratloser zurück als zuzuvor. Bei den 2 Zeit-Online-Zitaten würde ich beim ersten auch "destillieren" sagen, nicht "abstrahieren".